# Syncfusion GridGroupingControl, get the parent node from a child node

Tags: syncfusion

I use the syncfusion GridGroupingControl on which I databind an object. This object contains an array of another objet.

Person {
Name,
Lastname,
Orders[]
}

So in my gridgroupingcontrol I have

```
Persons
Name | Last
James| Doe
    Orders
    123524 | 12/15/2010 | stuffs
John | Smith
    Orders
    545541 | 12/31/2005 | stufffs
```

When I click on the order 123524 row of James Doe, I want to get the parent node which is James Doe.

I've tried everything like
e.ParentChildTable.getData()
e.ParentDisplayElement.getData()
e.ParentGroup.getData()
e.ParentSection.getData()
e.ParentTable.getData()
e.ParentTableDescriptor.getData()

most of the methods return null...

Whats the solution ?

Thanks guys !

John Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it's an OMG solution but it works !

```
e.Record.ParentDisplayElement.ParentChildTable.ParentNestedTable.ParentRecord.GetData()
```